# SQL Server 2008 и Net Send

Tags: sql-server

Как в всязке sql 2008 и windows server 2008 r2 использовать Alert на машину администратора с windows xp,

Answer (score 2):

Создать `job`, который будет по событию слать `net sent 191.168.0.1 "alarm"`
Ещё проще это сделать через готовые `maintance plans` (если у вас не sql express) там есть функция sql mail, которая отправляет письмо по событиям (job завершён / успешно неуспешно, привыген ресурс и прочее.)

Ещё можно использовать программу Event Entry(freeware) которая позволяет по событию в event viewer отправлять емейл заданному пользователю.